# Flip least significant one-bit by using negation of a size_t

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit

I've recently encountered a piece of code that supposedly works fine, but I don't quite understand why.

```cpp
size_t a = 19;
std::cout<<std::bitset<8>(a)<<std::endl;
a ^= a & -a;
std::cout<<std::bitset<8>(a)<<std::endl;
```

This piece of code will invert the least significant bit of a given unsigned integer. I would prefer to just write `a ^= 1;`, but I'm puzzled by why the piece of code above actually works. I would think that making an `unsigned int` negative will result in undefined behavior?

Comment: Careful: it flips the least significant *set bit* (the first set bit from the bottom), not the least significant bit (which might be a 0 or a 1). This code is not equivalent to `a ^= 1;` (but it is equivalent to `a &= a - 1;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a & -a` gives you the least significant 1-bit set in `a`. For an odd number it is indeed 1, but that's not the case in general of course.

Making an `unsigned` negative is a well-defined and occasionally useful notation: `-a` for positive `a` is `-a` + 2<sup>N</sup> where N is the number of bits in the type. An alternative to writing `size_t a = std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max();` is to write `size_t a = -1;` for example.

So `a ^= a & -a;` flips the least significant 1-bit to 0.

Rather clever really.

Comment: See also [\[conv.integral\]/p2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv#integral-2)

Answer (score 0):

As @Bathsheba has already pointed out, this trick gives you the least significant 1-bit set in a. However I would like to go into more detail why this happens.
C++ unsigned integer negation is equivalent to two's complement negation:

> #### Unary arithmetic operators
>
> [...] 
> The builtin unary minus operator calculates the negative of its promoted operand. For unsigned a, the value of -a is 2<sup>b</sup>
> -a, where b is the number of bits after promotion.

(see [cppreference/Arithmetic operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Unary_arithmetic_operators))

For two's complement numbers, a negation can be done as follows:

```cpp
unsigned a = ...;
a = ~a;
a += 1;
```

If it wasn't for the increment, then `~a` would have no bits in common with `a` and the result would be zero. This is the case for one's complement numbers. However, due to the increment, the last significant set 1-bit in `a` also becomes set. For example:

```cpp
 16      = 0b0001'0000
~16      = 0b1110'1111 = -17
~16 + 1  = 0b1111'0000 = -16
-16 & 16 = 0b0001'0000 =  16

 10      = 0b0000'1010
~10      = 0b1111'0101 = -11
~10 + 1  = 0b1111'0110 = -10
-10 & 10 = 0b0000'0010 =   2
```

`a ^= a & -a` then flips the least significant 1-bit to 0.
What this mathematically does is:

- round up to the next multiple of a power of two
- turn any power of 2 into 0
- 0 stays the same

---

Also note that as of C++20, signed numbers **must** be represented using two's complement. For example, this means that signed integer overflow is no longer undefined behavior.

> #### Range of values
>
> [...]
>
> Prior to C++20, the C++ Standard allowed any signed integer representation, and the minimum guaranteed range of N-bit signed integers was from -(2<sup>N-1</sup>-1) to +2<sup>N-1</sup>-1 (e.g. **-127** to **127** for a signed 8-bit type), which corresponds to the limits of one's complement or sign-and-magnitude.
>
> However, all C++ compilers use two's complement representation, and as of C++20, it is the only representation allowed by the standard, with the guaranteed range from -2<sup>N-1</sup> to +2<sup>N-1</sup>
> -1 (e.g. **-128** to **127** for a signed 8-bit type).

(See [cppreference/Fundamental types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Range_of_values))